# Получить input, чтобы при клике исчезал текст

Tags: javascript, input

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как достать `input` используя js, чтобы при клике исчезал текст в поле, если нет прямого доступа редактировать `input`.

Знаю, что можно прописать

```
onfocus="if (this.value=='Ваш текст') this.value='';" 
onblur="if (this.value==''){this.value='Ваш текст'}"
```

но получить прямой доступ к нему нет возможности, есть только id  и класс.

Answer (score 2):

"Достать" и отчистить `input` зная его идентификатор можно, например, вот так:

```
document.getElementById('input-id').value = '';
```